# What difference between Collections.sort() and sorting using streams?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that builds a pyramid of sorted numbers and returns two-dimensional array

```
public int[][] buildPyramid(List<Integer> inputNumbers) {
...
}
```

This unit test

```
@Test(expected = CannotBuildPyramidException.class) // class doen't have any logic, just extends RintimeException
    public void buildPyramid8() {
        List<Integer> input = Collections.nCopies(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1, 0);
        // run
        int[][] pyramid = pyramidBuilder.buildPyramid(input);
        // assert (exception)
    }
```

doesn't work if i use traditional method
 `Collections.sort(inputNumbers)`
So i have an exception

```
Java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<com.alex.demo.tasks.pyramid.CannotBuildPyramidException> but was<java.lang.OutOfMemoryError>
```

But if i use 
`List<Integer> sorted = inputNumbers.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());`

i don't have an exception. Why so?

Comment: The problem is probably in the `...` part

Comment: @Eran Quite possibly the most amusing comment all day `:-)`